# Is it possible to attach a debugging session to a running program in eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I'm writing a netscape iplanet plugin (on solaris/C using eclipse) which is basically a shared object with specific entry points, and I'd like to be able to debug the shared object with eclipse's debugger (gdb).
I remember doing something similar in AIX where you could make xldb attach to a running process. Is it possible to get eclipse to run gdb to attach to a running binary?
And should I expect grief because I want to debug a dynamically loaded piece of code?

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655853/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-debugging-session-to-a-running-program-in-eclipse-cdt/719936#719936?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes it is. You need to go to the Lauch Configuration Dialog and select "C++ Attach to ...". Depending on your Eclipse version there may be only one or more "C++ Attach to ..." variants available.

Answer (score 10):

I use Eclipse CDT for HP/UX remote environment. I'm not sure whether it will work for you:

1. have your app running on unix
2. go to Run / Debug Configurations / C/C++ Attach to Remote
3. click Debug and a list of processess will be shown
4. select the process you want to debug.

Comment: In step #1, how can I make sure the app doesn't run past the point I want to debug? (on HP-UX)

Comment: Hi, can you specify which plugin you are using? I am not able to find any option under Debug Configurations for C++ Attach To Remote I have C++ Remote Application.

Comment: @Hassaan hi you can write  int x = 1; while(x) { sleep(1000);} this will make sure code stops at someplace. If the symbol files are loaded and mapped then any breakpoints you set after will be hit and work like a charm.