# Debug external console program using Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, shell, cygwin

How can I use Eclipse to debug a (C/C++) console program running external from Eclipse? I'd like to click the Debug button to launch the external console (Cygwin shell in Windows; or Terminal in OS X) and break in main().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach your debug session to an external application:

[Is it possible to attach a debugging session to a running program in eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655853/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-debugging-session-to-a-running-program-in-eclipse-cdt)

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

If an alternative is fine, xxgdb should do most of what you need. And gdb, if you intend work from terminal. [refer this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xxgdb)

Answer (score 1):

[LiveOutput.com](http://www.liveoutput.com)

Not sure if this helps, but you can log messages to this website in a few lines of code (if your program has internet access).  Its like a cloud based console.