# Is it possible to start eclipse debug session from a script

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, debugging

I have a script, in which I run a C++ application.
Is it possible to start eclipse debug session from a script?
I use gdb 7.4

Comment: I can change the way I run the application in the script...

Comment: what debugger are you using?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. I use Luna eclipse, open my C++ project and run

Comment: The answer to  your question depends on the compiler/debugger you're using. I believe eclipse can use either clang++ or g++ for its c++ compiler, both of those require have their own debugger. Once you figure out which compiler/debugger you're using all you have to do is read how to launch your debug build from the debugger.

Comment: This should answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370972/how-to-attach-a-process-in-gdb

Comment: I use gdb 7.4 debugger

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to attach a debugging session to a running program in eclipse CDT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655853/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-debugging-session-to-a-running-program-in-eclipse-cdt)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but they dont solve my issue. Today I run the application from the script - with no debugging. After it is run - its already to late to start debugging. I need a way to start the debug session from the script.

Comment: or to enable Eclipse to automatically identify running this application, and attach the debugger to it