# cudaMemcpyToSymbol just hangs and never returns. GPU processing at 100%. Code works fine on K40 but not on V100

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, tesla

I have the following code snippet:

```
__constant__ int baseLineX[4000];
__constant__ int baseLineY[4000];
__constant__ int guideLineX[4000];
__constant__ int guideLineY[4000];
__constant__ int rectangleOffsets[8];

__constant__ float blurKernel[64];

<other code>

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    hostRectangleOffsets[i] = i;

cudaMemcpyToSymbol(rectangleOffsets, hostRectangleOffsets, 8*sizeof(int));
```

This code works fine on a Tesla K40 but not on a 16GB Tesla V100. (Even my laptop can run the code with a 4GB Quaddro M2200 GPU).

Code just hangs on the V100 and never returns from the cudaMemcpyToSymbol call but looks like it's still being processed on the GPU. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe problem is size of int on different platforms and GPUs?

Answer (score -2):

Well, you haven't provided a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): Your code doesn't compile and is missing statements, yet has (apparently) irrelevant statements. So - nobody can actually check.

I can still make several suggestions though:

1. Try using the asynchronous version of this call: [`cudaMemcpyToSymbolAsync()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc3551568f691baad5fb776b7656ecc05). At least your program won't hang...
2. Run your program or app in a debugger to begin with (e.g. nVIDIA's nSight on most systems, or their extension to Visual Studio on Windows); alternatively, attach a debugger to the hanging process ([MSVS instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx), [Eclipse instructions - old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655853/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-debugging-session-to-a-running-program-in-eclipse-cdt)).
3. Run the process with core dump enabled (if you're on a Unix'ish system), kill it when it hangs, then open the core dump in a debugger and you'll at least get the back-trace
4. Try rebuilding your program with less optimizations enabled - this sometimes helps, at least for diagnostical purposes (this can be combined with the previous suggestions).